How Do I Achieve This Wave/Liquid Gold Effect?
https://www.tiffany.com/fragrance/shop/all-fragrances/
Hello. I am trying to recreate something similar to the effect you see in the link provided above, where the perfume is interacting with the surface behind it. I'm currently trying to use the wave option in the canvas dynamic paint tab, however, it's nowhere near close. I'm starting to wonder if cloth physics are needed. On a different test, I got rid of the dynamic paint altogether, and tried using the weight proximity modifier, displace modifier, and weight painting together and still can't get it quite right. Then I tried combining dynamic paint with the weight proximity, and weight painting. Thank you.

To me that looks like the bottle is emerging from a pool of gold liquid.
